# "no result exception" for Spring @Service's

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, try-catch

I have multiple `@Service`'s in my Spring boot application which mainly make API calls to some external services.

Do Spring offers a custom Exception for a kind of a "404" exception? i.e. the item not found / there's no result for the requested key.

I'm aware of `NoSuchElementException` class but it doesn't seem to really fit here.

I guess I could create my own `NoResultException` but I'd like to follow the convention (if there's such)

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such exception provided by the Spring framework for the case of 404, or any other HttpStatus, for that matter.

You should ideally handle that in your service layer based on the API response and throw a custom exception which denotes the 404 case according to your domain. You can have a `@ControllerAdvice` which handles the specific exception and provides a custom response accordingly.

Comment: Okay, I thought so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you can use is `HttpStatusCodeException`. More details int the [documentations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpStatusCodeException.html). Example constructor is

```
HttpStatusCodeException(HttpStatus statusCode, java.lang.String statusText)
```

where you can provide your code, for example 404 and message. Thrown in service will be translated into the right http response.